# Rails 3 Many-to-many query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

Hello I want to create a query that goes something like this, *"Get me the variety which has the following ingredients(1,2,3)"*

Here are my models

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :varieties

class Variety < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
```

I have been breaking my head but I haven't been able to get it right, can someone help me out please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrected after Dylan's comment.  I broke up the where_clause into a multi-line string for readability sake.

```
ingredient_list = [1,2,3]
where_clause = %{
varieties.id IN
(SELECT v.variety_id FROM 
(SELECT variety_id, count(*) as cnt FROM ingredients_varieties WHERE ingredient_id in (#{ingredient_list.join(',')}) GROUP BY variety_id) v 
WHERE v.cnt = #{ingredient_list.size})
} 
Variety.where(where_clause)
```

Comment: I think this will give you any `Variety` that has at least one of the ingredients, whereas I think he wants it to include all 3 ingredients.

Comment: First of all Thank you... The first query looked great, but the problem is that I need the Variety, that contains exactly those ingredients, not at least one

Comment: Hey man you are going to kill me but I'm still getting an error,"SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: variety_id", I think it it is trying to access the non existing column "variety_id" from the Variety model instead of the join table... Or am I wrong?

Comment: Hey Brian that actually worked really wel but the problem is that it gets the variety if it includes at least the (1,2,3) Ingredients. But if the variety also includes the (4) ingredient it also gets it and I need to get the Variety only when it includes EXACTLY (1,2,3) ingredients, but Thanks any way

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about performance(and we know not to optimize prematurely), but this is definitely more readable than pure SQL:

```
@ingredients = Ingredient.includes(:varieties).find [1,2,3]
@varieties = @ingredients.collect(&:varieties).inject(&:&).reject{|v| v.ingredients.size != @ingredients.size}
```

Comment: Hey, RocketR that actually worked really wel but the problem is that it gets the variety if it includes at least the (1,2,3) Ingredients. But if the variety also includes the (4) ingredient it also gets it and I need to get the Variety only when it includes EXACTLY (1,2,3) ingredients, but Thanks any way

Comment: @rogeliog I updated the code to reject the varieties with more than 3 ingredients.